# How best to show server availability over a 24 hour period?

Tags: info-visualisation, charts, timeline

I have a customer who asked me to provide a "Server Availability" chart for the last 24 hours that looks like this one:

Y represents hours (0 - 23); X represents minutes (0 - 59)

In this example you see that the server wasn't available during 20:24 - 20:28 .

[image]

Since I provide COTS (Commercial off the shelf) I'm wondering if this chart really provides useful UI and information. Do you think so?

Comment: If i understand this chart correctly, you also have outages in the morning at 1:45, 2:50, 3:45 and 6:45. The only advantage i can see is, that if everything is ok, the chart is empty, so it really only shows the relevant datapoints. It is not as easy to read off the bat though, as a "normal" chart with Y being available or not and X being the time would be.

Comment: The flaw here is taking linear time and chopping it up along two axis. That MIGHT be useful if the goal is to find an hourly pattern but beyond that need, it seems completely irrelevant.

Comment: That graph is using two axis just for the sake of using two axis. To someone with a mathematical background, that *may* seem intuitive, but in the end it's only confusing. I have to look on the y-axis to get my hour, and the match it to get minutes. In the end, the visualization actually makes it even harder to visualize what you're trying to convey.

Answer (score 45):

I have seen the following visualization used to represent down time and it has been effective:

[image]

The illustration in the question requires too much thinking.

The linear time line works well for a 24 hour timespan.

Comment: Thank you. I thought about this one in the beginning. The problem is that if I monitor the server every 1 minute, I need 1440 pixels. If I take a sample every 30 minutes (as I tend to do) I need 2880 pixels... that's the reason I moved to a matrix.

Can you tell me where have you seen that? I'm wondering how they cope with that issue. Thx.

Comment: You could show it in a small bar graph like the one above, and for every pixel show if it was down in that period (here, for 480px that'd be a 33mins to a pixel). More accurate times could be listed in a table.

Comment: @ThorinII, how would you listed this in a table? Do you mean to split hours? e.g. split it to 4 lines (each one represents 6 hours). Thx

Comment: When showing it as a table, it'd be a compliment to the chart. It'd tell the user 'the site was down here, here, and here...' and for how long each time - ie  just a listing of events

Comment: If you need to show more detail in the representation above why not just let users click on the hour showing yellow to display another chart with the actual outage times ?

Comment: @user1762109, It's probably enough to know/tell there was a huge or short downtime. But if a very accurate display is required by your customer: A) you could render a small and a full resolution chart and show the part of the full resolution image using a magnifier or B) or just show a small tooltip showing details when hovering the yellow part or C) modify Charles' design, so that it's a small bargraph where the height (Y-axis) denotes the duration in minutes. (+1 For this answer because it's simple and clear)

Answer (score 10):

This is the way Pingdom chose to visualize it in their Public Status Pages:

[image: 24h Uptime Graph]

(Disclosure: I was the front-end web developer who implemented this graph back in 2010, but not the designer or originator of the concept.)

Answer (score 9):

An aside: COTS stands for *Commercial* Off The Shelf.

Per the chart - it tells me nothing. Both the X and Y axis are so deep I have to following an enormous gulf in order to guess that the server was down *roughly* in the timeframe of 20:24-20:28.

Why are there 4 lines in-between the hour lines when they only jump by 2 hours?

My eye also has to wander a great deal, and I have to think a lot, in order to pull out a timeline from this chart. Times *earlier* in the day are in the lower right with times *later* in the day in the upper left. Add a bunch more dots and the user is going to freak out trying to figure out time blocks.

A simple listing when a server went down, and when it came back up, would be easier to read and take up less space (assuming your server isn't going down an enormous amount).

Fancy visuals do not necessarily make information easier to parse. If you really must have one, show something that presents the information in a linear progression - such as a timeline - which is how people see time.

Comment: Yes, I messed up too (I've fixed it)! :) Note your question calls it out as "cut of the shelf".

Comment: I am not the OP! I noticed your edit and deleted my comment. :-) Those 4 lines between the hours are obviously convenient 24 minute steps that make no sense on a full hour scale of course ;-)

Answer (score 9):

[UptimeRobot](http://uptimerobot.com/) is a tool for monitoring server downtimes (I'm just a user, no other connection whatsoever). They're showing a small graph on the left side for the up-/downtimes for every watched server in the last 24 hours (I edited the image because none of my watched servers had a downtime in this period). If you click on one of the bars, you see details on the right side for this specific server:
[image: Uptimerobot]

[Bigger image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IcHqY.jpg)

Comment: This is awesome. Nice to see some web philanthropy.

Comment: Much more clear.